# R - transforming data

Tags: r

I have a table like this:

```
   Anno Mese     `No quotations`
      <int> <chr>                  <int>
    1  2018 Feb                    169
    2  2018 Jan                    147
    3  2019 Feb                    102
    4  2019 Jan                    222
```

I'd like to transform data like this

```
              Feb-2018   Jan-2018
No quotation    169         147
```

and so on. Basically I need time on columns.

I tried `melt` and `reshape` with no success.

I can use `dcast`

```
dcast(report1, . ~ Anno+Mese)
```

and that's the output

```
 . 2018_febbraio 2018_gennaio 2019_febbraio 2019_gennaio
1 .           169          147           102          222
```

while I'd prefer to have

```
                  2018_febbraio 2018_gennaio 2019_febbraio 2019_gennaio
No_quotation            169          147           102          222
```

And also I could have more than one numeri values ( besides No quotations column)

software R.
Thanks

Comment: This is ultimately multi-part: (1) figure out how to combine `Anno` and `Mese` into one column (perhaps with `paste`); (2) look into `tidyr::spread` or `data.table::dcast`. (I always have difficult with `reshape` and `reshape2::*`, to be honest, so I strongly encourage you to try the other two I just mentioned.)

Answer (score 0):

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
dt<-fread("    2018 Feb                    169
                2018 Jan                    147
                2019 Feb                    102
                2019 Jan                    222", header = FALSE)
dt
# V1  V2  V3
# 1: 2018 Feb 169
# 2: 2018 Jan 147
# 3: 2019 Feb 102
# 4: 2019 Jan 222
```

**code**

```
dcast(dt, . ~ paste0(V2, "-", V1), value.var = "V3")
#    . Feb-2018 Feb-2019 Jan-2018 Jan-2019
# 1: .      169      102      147      222
```